# Need reference to open source play framework based scala apps

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sample

I'm about to start small project using play2 and curious if there are any other sample applications available except ones which are coming together with play distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend of mine wrote a little sharing project with play2 and scalate (jade templates), hope this will help you https://github.com/4e6/play2-filesharing

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot sample applications on GitHub. I member just a few ones:

- [Sample applications](https://github.com/playforscala/sample-applications) from the [Play for Scala book](http://www.manning.com/hilton/)
- [Guardian Website](https://github.com/guardian/frontend)
- [Using freemarker as template engine with Play 2](https://github.com/guillaumebort/play2-freemarker-demo#readme)
- [example webapp which generates a iOS Passbook Pass using passkit4j and Play! Framework 2.0.4](https://github.com/poornerd/passbook-test)
- [WebPipe -  play2 and command line tools](https://github.com/bobylito/webPipe)

Comment: (I'm very new to Github!) HOw did you find these? Searching for 'com.typesafe.play' (so as to catch project/plugins.sbt) catches only two. Searching for play-framework yields too many. 

Is there a specific way to find high-profile projects?

Comment: I didn't used the GitHub search function, I just mention some projects that I have looked for myself. When you follow f.ex. the playframework mailing list you will discover a lot more interesting GitHub Play projects.